# Munin restart services like monit

Tags: munin

The German monit wiki page says:

> Die gleichen Funktionen, aber mit einer aufwendigeren grafischen
>   Web-Oberfläche versehen, bietet Munin

Translation

```
Same functions (as monit) but with a more complex GUI offers Munin
```

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Monit

Did I miss something or does munin really offer same functions like monit. 
If so how can I

- monitor Apache, Postgresql, ssh and
- restart them if something goes wrong?

by use of munin / munin-node

thanks,

t book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Munin does not provide any of the same features as Monit.  That's a page hosted on a public wiki, so you can't just trust anything posted there ;)